# Hiding elements within on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make it so when my "cancel deletion" link is clicked, the links that are confirming whether to delete or not disappear and the original delete button reappears. In essence I am trying to make a confirmation window, but have it occur inside the current document rather than as a popup box.

All my code works except for this bit:

```
  $(document).on("click",".delete_button",function(){
    $(".delete_button").hide();
    $(".confirm_links").show();
    return false;
  });
```

When I click the `delete_button` link, the `confirm_links` is shown but `delete_button` fails to `hide`. I think `delete_button` is not hiding because I am passing it as a parameter in `.on()` and then trying to modify it within the handler I am passing. I think that I need some special syntax to reference, maybe something akin to self, but I am unsure where to go from here. Any advice greatly appreciated. Kthnx

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vvckp/1/

Comment: Have you tried $(this).hide() rather than $('.delete_button').hide() ?

Comment: Does $(this).hide(); not work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zvug/ working for me..

Comment: This code should work regardless of using `$(this)` or not

Comment: I just tried $(this) instead and it still did not work. Should I posts full code?

Comment: Are you sure your delete button doesn't also match `.confirm_links`?

Comment: I guess you do have an event handler for showing `.delete_button` if the users does not wish to proceed. Can you show us that and the markup surrounding `.delete_button`. Or, better still, can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vvckp/

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 update the fiddle code so it uses the generated html

Comment: A more helpful jsfiddle is one that uses **HTML as seen by your browser**. Server-side code is just good for the server and is not very helpful to JS/jQuery and the humans that are trying to help you.

Comment: Alright cool, sorry about that. I am not familiar with JSfiddle. So I should just copy and paste my HTML source code into the JSfiddle HTML window?

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 yea but just get the relevant part

Comment: @Huangism Cool, just updated it

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 you forgot to update the question with the new fiddle

Comment: @Huangism, how e-barressing. Fixed

Comment: As you can see, http://jsfiddle.net/7Zvug/1/ .... works fine as it is. Maybe including a little more markup and the rest of your jQuery would help to find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Oh your delete button is also a submit button

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 you fiddle is missing jquery http://jsfiddle.net/Vvckp/3/ as you can see it works. I don't know if this is the same issue you are having on your computer or not.